# Why C# don't convert ',' symbol to double when changing region to en?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, double

I try to find information, but didn't find the reasons for wrong conversion. 
Help me, please!

Source: https://github.com/era312/UWP-Calculator/blob/master/src/calculator/MainPage.xaml.cs
Video with proble: https://youtu.be/nCttAnnSKrI

Comment: Post code and relevant info here, not just as external links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have tested, but we could not reproduce this issue. And I found strange symbol in your calculator. The default decimal symbol is **"."** but not **","**. Please try reset customize Format.

Process steps:

**Control Panel - > Region - >Additional Settings->Reset.**

[image]